# Jquery : Menu active when click

Tags: jquery, css

I create the menu  :

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>                
        <a href="#" onclick="load(1);return false;"> Team Install</a> 
    </li>
    <li>                
        <a href="#" onclick="load(2);return false;"> PC and Laptop Service</a>
    </li>
    <li>                
        <a href="#" onclick="load(3);return false;"> Web Design and Internet Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>                
        <a href="#" onclick="load(4);return false;"> Software and Database Dev.</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="LoadMe"></div>
```

And this is what I do in jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#LoadMe").load('/Service2.html');
        $('#menu a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('selectedcategoryServices');
    });

    function load(num) {
        $("#LoadMe").load('/Service' + num + '.html');
    }

</script>
```

But the menu doesn't have the `selectedcategoryServices` when I clicked it ready, could any one tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
$("a").click(function(){
     $("a.selectedcategoryServices").removeClass("selectedcategoryServices");
     $(this).addClass('selectedcategoryServices');

 });
```

check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJq7x/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I've added urls for `href` attributes and removed `onclick` from your markup.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/Service1.html"> Team Install</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Service2.html"> PC and Laptop Service</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Service3.html"> Web Design and Internet Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Service4.html"> Software and Database Dev.</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="LoadMe"></div>
```

.

With this markup you can use this to achieve the effect you're looking for

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu a").click("on", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});

function load(url) {
    $("#LoadMe").load(url, function() {
        $("#menu").find("a[href=\"" + url + "\"]").addClass("selectedcategoryServices");
    });
}
```

FYI: [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) :)

Comment: Thanks Andreas, The menu is active, but it is not remove the class when I click to the other menus.